# Efficiently compute max of an array of 8 elements in arm neon

Tags: c++, arm, intrinsics, neon

How do I find max element in array of 8 bytes, 8 shorts or 8 ints?
I may need just the position of the max element, value of the max element, or both of them.

[For example](https://godbolt.org/g/5mj4FH):

```
unsigned FindMax8(const uint32_t src[8]) // returns position of max element
{
    unsigned ret = 0;
    for (unsigned i=0; i<8; ++i)
    {
        if (src[i] > src[ret])
            ret = i;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

At `-O2` clang unrolls the loop but it does not use neon, which should give decent perf boost (because it eliminates many data dependent branches?)

For 8 bytes and 8 shorts approach should be simpler as entire array can be loaded into a single q-register. For arm64 this should be much simpler with vmaxv_u16, but how do I make it efficient in 32-bit neon?

As noted by Marc in comments, when function is changed to return max value [GCC auto vectorizer generates](https://godbolt.org/g/YVK7CF) the following for neon64:

```
ldr q0, [x0, 16]
ld1r {v2.4s}, [x0]
ldr q1, [x0]
umax v0.4s, v0.4s, v2.4s
umax v0.4s, v0.4s, v1.4s
umaxv s0, v0.4s
umov w0, v0.s[0]
```

I have one function that does quite complex math and at the end of computation I end up with `uint32x4_t res` result and all I need is to get index of the max element. This single piece is the slowest part of the code, *by far* slower than the rest of the rest of this math-heavy function.

I tried three different approaches (from slowest to fastest according to profiler):

- full computation using neon with final single 32-bit result transfer from neon to arm.
- vst1q_u32(src, res) and then using regular C code to find index of the max element.
- vmov to four 32-bit arm registers using vget_lane_u64 two times and then using some bit-shifts to figure out index of the max element.

[Here's fastest version that I was able to get](https://godbolt.org/g/7Hx9U4):

```
unsigned compute(unsigned short *input)
{
    uint32x4_t result = vld1q_u32((uint32_t*)(input));
    // some computations...
    // ... and at the end I end up with res01 and res23
    // and I need to get index of max element from them:
    uint32x2_t res01 = vget_low_u32(result);
    uint32x2_t res23 = vget_high_u32(result);

    // real code below:
    uint64_t xres01 = vget_lane_u64(vreinterpret_u64_u32(res01), 0);
    uint64_t xres23 = vget_lane_u64(vreinterpret_u64_u32(res23), 0);
    unsigned ret = 0;
    uint32_t xmax0 = (uint32_t)(xres01 & 0xffffffff);
    uint32_t xmax1 = (uint32_t)(xres01 >> 32);
    uint32_t xmax2 = (uint32_t)(xres23 & 0xffffffff);
    uint32_t xmax3 = (uint32_t)(xres23 >> 32);
    if (xmax1 > xmax0)
    {
        xmax0 = xmax1;
        ret = 1;
    }
    if (xmax2 > xmax0)
    {
        xmax0 = xmax2;
        ret = 2;
    }
    if (xmax3 > xmax0)
        ret = 3;
    return ret;
}
```

Version using full neon computation does this:

- using vmax/vpmax find max element
- set u32x4_t to the max element
- using vceq set max elements to 0xffffffff
- load u32x4_t mask with with `{1u<<31, 1u<<30, 1u<<29, 1u<<28 }`
- do vand with the mask
- pairwise add or vorr to collapse all 4 values to a single one.
- using vclz set all to index of the max element

Maybe issue somewhere else, see [actual code](https://godbolt.org/g/x266Pa) that I'm trying to optimize. [My optimized version](https://godbolt.org/g/MQH86d) where only the last piece needs to be improved. Somehow profiler shows that 80% time is spent in the last lines where I compute max index. Any ideas? Changing that simple c-loop to pairs of regs improves entire function by 20-30%. Note, according to profiler the two vst1_u32 are the ones where function spents most of the time.

What other approach could I try?

**Update:**
It seems that slow down at the end of the function isn't related to the code. I'm not sure why, but when [I tried to run different versions of the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951100/debug-data-neon-performance-hazards-in-arm-neon-code) depending on the order in which I called them I got timings change 3-4x times. Also, with different testing it seem that full neon version is fastest if there is no stall at the end of the function and I'm not sure why that stall happen. For that reason [I created a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951100/debug-data-neon-performance-hazards-in-arm-neon-code) to figure out why.

Comment: Maybe for such a short loop it doesn't provide any benefit. Have you benchmarked it against hand-written NEON code?

Comment: Yes, I benchmarked it, it does provide benefit. I'm doing for now simple intrinsics before I decide which parts (if any) would benefit from standalone asm.

Comment: It is easier if you only want the value (`return src[ret];`). Then gcc generates umax+umax+umaxv.

Comment: Getting the max value is easy, but the index isn't. There is an efficient way doing this, but it needs a matrix transpose after the main loop, and thus, `intrinsux` will generate FUBAR machine codes for certain, and this flat overhead will negate all the performance gain for such a short loop, even when written in assembly.

Comment: Surprisingly, I have quite complex code and the last piece of it that returns max index from uint32_t[4] is the slowest point according to profiler (mainly because of slow NEON -> arm transfer perhaps) but I'm not sure, so I'm trying different approaches to see which one is the best.

Comment: I added fastest version that I was able to come up with.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE Is your approach about VNEG -> VZIP -> VSLI -> move to arm and a few arm instructions?

Comment: @Pavel I never move anythin g to ARM registers inside the loop.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE so, what's the approach to get max index from uint32x4_t using `vtrn` that you mentioned? High-level explanation