# Debug data/neon performance hazards in arm neon code

Tags: optimization, arm, profiling, neon

Originally the problem appeared when I tried to [optimize an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928749/efficiently-compute-max-of-an-array-of-8-elements-in-arm-neon) for neon arm and some minor part of it was taking 80% of according to profiler. I tried to test to see what can be done to improve it and for that I created array of function pointers to different versions of my optimized function and then I run them in the loop to see in profiler which one performs better:

```
typedef unsigned(*CalcMaxFunc)(const uint16_t a[8][4], const uint16_t b[4][4]);
CalcMaxFunc CalcMaxFuncs[] =
{
    CalcMaxFunc_NEON_0,
    CalcMaxFunc_NEON_1,
    CalcMaxFunc_NEON_2,
    CalcMaxFunc_NEON_3,
    CalcMaxFunc_C_0
};


int N = sizeof(CalcMaxFunc) / sizeof(CalcMaxFunc[0]);
for (int i = 0; i < 10 * N; ++i)
{
    auto f = CalcMaxFunc[i % N];
    unsigned retI = f(a, b);

    // just random code to ensure that cpu waits for the results
    // and compiler doesn't optimize it away
    if (retI > 1000000)
        break;
    ret |= retI;
}
```

I got surprising results: performance of a function was totally depend on its position within CalcMaxFuncs array. For example, when I swapped CalcMaxFunc_NEON_3 to be first it would be 3-4 times slower and according to profiler it would stall at the last bit of the function where it tried to move data from neon to arm register.

So, what does it make stall sometimes and not in other times? BY the way, I profile on iPhone6 in xcode if that matters.

When I intentionally introduced neon pipeline stalls by mixing-in some floating point division between calling these functions in the loop I eliminated unreliable behavior, now all of them perform the same regardless of the order in which they were called. So, why in the first place did I have that problem and what can I do to eliminate it in actual code?

**Update:**
I tried to create a simple test function and then optimize it in stages and see how I could possibly avoid neon->arm stalls.
Here's the test runner function:

```
void NeonStallTest()
{
    int findMinErr(uint8_t* var1, uint8_t* var2, int size);
    srand(0);
    uint8_t var1[1280];
    uint8_t var2[1280];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(var1); ++i)
    {
        var1[i] = rand();
        var2[i] = rand();
    }
#if 0 // early exit?
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
        var1[i] = var2[i];
#endif
    int ret = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<10000000; ++i)
        ret += findMinErr(var1, var2, sizeof(var1));
    exit(ret);
}
```

And `findMinErr` is this:

```
int findMinErr(uint8_t* var1, uint8_t* var2, int size)
{
    int ret = 0;
    int ret_err = INT_MAX;
    for (int i = 0; i < size / 16; ++i, var1 += 16, var2 += 16)
    {
        int err = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 16; ++j)
        {
            int x = var1[j] - var2[j];
            err += x * x;
        }
        if (ret_err > err)
        {
            ret_err = err;
            ret = i;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Basically it it does sum of squared difference between each uint8_t[16] block and returns index of the block pair that has lowest squared difference. So, then [I rewrote it in neon intrisics](https://godbolt.org/g/8DU8NB) (no particular attempt was made to make it fast, as it's not the point):

```
int findMinErr_NEON(uint8_t* var1, uint8_t* var2, int size)
{
    int ret = 0;
    int ret_err = INT_MAX;
    for (int i = 0; i < size / 16; ++i, var1 += 16, var2 += 16)
    {
        int err;
        uint8x8_t var1_0 = vld1_u8(var1 + 0);
        uint8x8_t var1_1 = vld1_u8(var1 + 8);
        uint8x8_t var2_0 = vld1_u8(var2 + 0);
        uint8x8_t var2_1 = vld1_u8(var2 + 8);
        int16x8_t s0 = vreinterpretq_s16_u16(vsubl_u8(var1_0, var2_0));
        int16x8_t s1 = vreinterpretq_s16_u16(vsubl_u8(var1_1, var2_1));
        uint16x8_t u0 = vreinterpretq_u16_s16(vmulq_s16(s0, s0));
        uint16x8_t u1 = vreinterpretq_u16_s16(vmulq_s16(s1, s1));
#ifdef __aarch64__1
        err = vaddlvq_u16(u0) + vaddlvq_u16(u1);
#else
        uint32x4_t err0 = vpaddlq_u16(u0);
        uint32x4_t err1 = vpaddlq_u16(u1);
        err0 = vaddq_u32(err0, err1);
        uint32x2_t err00 = vpadd_u32(vget_low_u32(err0), vget_high_u32(err0));
        err00 = vpadd_u32(err00, err00);
        err = vget_lane_u32(err00, 0);
#endif

        if (ret_err > err)
        {
            ret_err = err;
            ret = i;
#if 0 // enable early exit?
            if (ret_err == 0)
                break;
#endif
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Now, `if (ret_err > err)` is clearly data hazard. Then I [manually "unrolled" loop by two](https://godbolt.org/g/8nKKqN) and modified code to use err0 and err1 and check them after performing next round of compute. According to profiler I got some improvements. In simple neon loop I got roughly 30% of entire function spent in the two lines `vget_lane_u32` followed by `if (ret_err > err)`. After I unrolled by two these operations started to take 25% (e.g. I got roughly 10% overall speedup). Also, check armv7 version, there is only 8 instructions between when err0 is set (`vmov.32 r6, d16[0]`) and when it's accessed (`cmp r12, r6`). T

Note, in the code early exit is ifdefed out. Enabling it would make function even slower. If I unrolled it by four and changed to use four `errN` variables and deffer check by two rounds then I still saw `vget_lane_u32` in profiler taking too much time. When I checked generated asm, appears that compiler destroys all the optimizations attempts because it reuses some of the `errN` registers which effectively makes CPU access results of `vget_lane_u32` much earlier than I want (and I aim to delay access by 10-20 instructions). Only when I unrolled by 4 and marked all four errN as volatile `vget_lane_u32` totally disappeared from the radar in profiler, however, the `if (ret_err > errN)` check obviously got slow as hell as now these probably ended up as regular stack variables overall these 4 checks in 4x manual loop unroll started to take 40%. Looks like with proper manual asm it's possible to make it work properly: have early loop exit, while avoiding neon->arm stalls and have some arm logic in the loop, however, extra maintenance required to deal with arm asm makes it 10x more complex to maintain that kind of code in a large project (that doesn't have any armasm).

**Update:**

Here's sample stall when moving data from neon to arm register. To implement early exist I need to move from neon to arm once per loop. This move alone takes more than 50% of entire function according to sampling profiler that comes with xcode. I tried to add lots of noops before and/or after the mov, but nothing seems to affect results in profiler. I tried to use vorr d0,d0,d0 for noops: no difference. What's the reason for the stall, or the profiler simply shows wrong results?

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't profile anything on out-of-order SoCs such as the Ax series on iPhones since the ooo engine is way too tolerant, and thus, the results are deceivingly optimistic. The `Galaxy A5/A7` are the best platforms for `aarch64` profiling while the `Galaxy J5/J7` for `aarch32`

Comment: Where are the variables `a` and `b` declared/initialized? And how do they serve as function arguments?

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE `a` and `b` are declared as stack variables and they store data generated by neon. I did some calculations and seems that it's a neon->arm stall that takes 10-20 cycles. What I don't understand is: why do I get much better results when moving to 64-bit uint (a pair of r-registers in A32)? Regarding profiling on androids: do they even have any decent tools?

Comment: NEON->ARM mov costs 14 cycles of hazard to be precise. It's a switching hazard, not computation time. You can "hide" this hazard by performing 14 movs consecutively.

Comment: I'll try to verify that. Basically if I stuff dummy movs (neon or arm?) before function returns then I should hide the impact, right?

Comment: no. Any other NEON instruction will be executed after the hazard then. Try ARM ones instead.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE when the hazard happens, is arm completely stalled? If I move from neon to `r0`, and then right away try to increment `r1`, will it wait 14 cycles, or only if I try to use `r0` it will wait?

Comment: @As far as I know, yes. The only instructions that can be executed during this are other `vmov`s NEON>ARM. I will check this.

Comment: I have a function where I need to compute 16 rounds of some operations and then select result from the best round. There is however a good chance of early exit: first round could possibly produce best possible result. If I try to add a check for best possible result and early exit in the 16-round loop my function runs 10 times slower because of neon to arm stall. That's why I want to understand stalls and how I could possibly code it to avoid stall and have early exit (e.g. I could move result from first round to arm, then compute second round in neon, check best exit from first round).

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE regarding your suggested test arm devices. How do you profile with them? AFAIK all google/android tools are nowhere near comparable in quality to xcode and are total time wasters. I used to use RVDS 10 years ago and it had cycle accurate profiler. What's the current suggested approach to profile arm code ;) ?

Comment: Cycle counting doesn't make much sense on out-of-order cores unless you are using ARM's Streamline, attached to dedicated pins of a board running Linux with dedicated codes built-in in the kernel level. Android Studio offers a profiler which I never used, hence I cannot tell you anything about its quality. Measuring the execution time in ms has been sufficient for my needs. Anyway, measuring the execution time on an in-order cores is much more accurate than counting approximate cycles on an out-of-order machine such as iPhones.

Comment: Yes, since the day it came out I was never able to run their gator driver and use their streamline profiler. They clearly have problems getting their tools working. I agree profiling on iPhone perhaps isn't the best idea, but at least with thier sampling profiler I get approximation of how much time each line of code takes, so you can reasonably guess what's wrong with the code and where exactly the problem is.

Comment: You could buy ARM's DS-5 Ultimate Edition for $7,000+. It offers an emulator that does the cycle counting. You can have a test run for one month for free. (per account/network MAC)

Comment: I tried to install trial and so far 4x unroll with armcc is much better: it uses 4 different registers for `errN` and doesn't touch them for many opcodes after moving to any of them from neon. Just need to figure out how to use object file produced with armcc with xcode (or possibly convert arm's asm to gas style asm that works with xcode) to test the result with profiler. Regarding cycle accurate profiler: before ds-5 they used to have RVDS that worked well for me, I wasn't never able to get similar functionality from DS-5.

Comment: The object files are binary compatible on anything that runs ARM. You just have to create a static library `.a` file by `armar`, link it, then call the function just like any external C function.