# Efficiently count number of distinct values in 16-byte buffer in arm neon

Tags: c++, arm, intrinsics, neon

Here's the basic algorithm to count number of distinct values in a buffer:

```
unsigned getCount(const uint8_t data[16])
{
    uint8_t pop[256] = { 0 };
    unsigned count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    {
        uint8_t b = data[i];
        if (0 == pop[b])
            count++;
        pop[b]++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Can this be done somehow in neon efficiently by loading into a q-reg and doing some bit magic? Alternatively, can I efficiently say that `data` has all elements identical, or contains only two distinct values or more than two?

For example, using `vminv_u8` and `vmaxv_u8` I can find min and max elements and if they are equal I know that `data` has identical elements. If not, then I can `vceq_u8` with min value and `vceq_u8` with max value and then `vorr_u8` these results and compare that I have all 1-s in the result. Basically, in neon it can be done this way. Any ideas how to make it better?

```
unsigned getCountNeon(const uint8_t data[16])
{
    uint8x16_t s = vld1q_u8(data);
    uint8x16_t smin = vdupq_n_u8(vminvq_u8(s));
    uint8x16_t smax = vdupq_n_u8(vmaxvq_u8(s));
    uint8x16_t res = vdupq_n_u8(1);
    uint8x16_t one = vdupq_n_u8(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 14; ++i) // this obviously needs to be unrolled
    {
        s = vbslq_u8(vceqq_u8(s, smax), smin, s); // replace max with min
        uint8x16_t smax1 = vdupq_n_u8(vmaxvq_u8(s));
        res = vaddq_u8(res, vaddq_u8(vceqq_u8(smax1, smax), one));
        smax = smax1;
    }
    res = vaddq_u8(res, vaddq_u8(vceqq_u8(smax, smin), one));
    return vgetq_lane_u8(res, 0);
}
```

With some optimizations and improvements perhaps a 16-byte block can be processed in 32-48 neon instructions. Can this be done better in arm? Unlikely

Some background why I ask this question. As I'm working on an algorithm I'm trying different approaches at processing data and I'm not sure yet what exactly I'll use at the end. Information that might be of use:

- count of distinct elements per 16-byte block
- value that repeats most per 16-byte block
- average per block
- median per block
- speed of light?.. that's a joke, it cannot be computed in neon from 16-byte block :)

so, I'm trying stuff, and before I use any approach I want to see if that approach can be well optimized. For example, average per block will be memcpy speed on arm64 basically.

Comment: No need to do  the post incr in `pop[b]++`  just do this `pop[b]=1` since their is no requirement to determine the number of duplicates of each byte. This may help the cache by avoiding read alter write.

Comment: for the purpose of the question it's not much relevant, in my actual code I do use it, so it ended up here.

Comment: How uint8_t data[16] is 16 byte buffer

Comment: @Kapil: `uint8_t` is 1 byte, 8 bits, defined in `stdint.h`

Comment: Semi-related: [Fallback implementation for conflict detection in AVX2](//stackoverflow.com/q/44843518) is about finding out if there are any repeated (32-bit) elements or not, without finding where they are or what they are.  (Useful as an optimistic fast-path check for scatter/gather conflicts, when the common case is no duplicates).  I just compared every element with every other element using 3 shuffles, 4 compares, and 3 ORs on the results.

Comment: Do you need C or C++?

Comment: @Red.Wave does that matter? Both are ok

Comment: Microcontroller world is dominated by C but the tag is C++. I was considering std::bitset, but changed my mind. That would shrink the amount of memory for data by a factor of 8. But ...

Comment: I notice that a bunch of your questions are asking about using NEON to optimize for 8 or 16 data elements. X86 and ARM CPU's are designed for working with large data sets. Making best use of the cache, hiding load latency and instruction interleaving is how you can optimize these kinds of problems. A single SIMD register's worth of data loses all hope of being optimized due to the load/store latency and the pipeline stalls caused by needing immediate results.

Comment: Why are your problems always so small? Yes, there is a solution, but it will be slower for such a short array.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE I don't want to post long complicated questions. Easy questions give some good hints for me how to build and modify algorithms to take advantage of possible optimizations. Also these might help other as well (and complex questions have limited use). All these simple 8-16 byte questions are running in giant loops hundreds of thousand times, so, unrolling it a few times or parallelizing it is always an option. But before that I need to figure out what approach to take and that why I ask about possibilities to handle simple cases in neon.

Comment: @BitBank Off course I do not use immediately results from neon operations and they are repeated and interleaved heavily in my actual code and I do all that while doing profiling. If it was just these simple operations then it would be 10x slower than basic C code.

Comment: @Pavel - your 'small set' questions will get misleading answers. The optimized solution for larger data sets will have the 8/16 issue as the final step. If done properly, the (normally inefficient) final output step will be overshadowed by the efficient solution for the majority of the data. By asking the questions the way you do, you're wasting the experts' time/experience on solving the wrong end of the problem.

Comment: @BitBank: x86 actually has no problem using SIMD for single small-array problems, e.g. [finding the min element of `int64_t input[8]`](//stackoverflow.com/q/31623383) can be efficient without needing to do it for multiple 8-element arrays in parallel.  With AVX512, it will be lower latency than scalar, as well as better throughput (lower impact on surrounding code).  It helps that all x86 CPUs are out-of-order, as well as not stalling for XMM->integer and having `pmovmskb` (high bits of vector elements -> integer bitmap, 1c latency).  SSE2 is a lot better for stuff like `strchr` than NEON.

Comment: @Pavel: Bitbank's criticism is totally justified for ARM, though: people aren't usually going to post solutions that suck for a single array if you don't give any hint in the question that doing it in parallel for many small inputs is useful.

Comment: @Pavel: your loop has 5 NEON operations vs. 4 in mine (or I guess 5 including the transfer to ARM).  But yours can't ever end early, even if mostly-duplicate vectors are the common case.

Comment: @PeterCordes the problem there is that it has branch based on data that comes from neon, this will be very slow.

Comment: @Pavel: Did you read my update?  You can transfer multiple values from NEON->ARM with only one stall, so you can amortize that 14-cycle stall over 8 transfers.  Is that not correct?  If most vectors only have 8 or fewer unique elements, mine should be at least as good as yours.  (It needs more ARM operations, but with predicated execution that should be fast.  You could maybe even schedule that work to fill the stall during the next NEON->ARM transfer.)  I don't have any ARM hardware to test on, or a cycle-accurate simulator.

Comment: From my limited experience if it's one stall and the rest of code flow does not depend on it, then it might be ok. But if you unroll it and modify to remove branches then it will become very similar to what I did (possibly with better count of ops).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you're expecting a lot of duplicates**, and can *efficiently* get a horizontal min with `vminv_u8`, this might be better than scalar.  Or not, maybe NEON->ARM stalls for the loop condition kill it. >.<  But it should be possible to mitigate that with unrolling (and saving some info in registers to figure out how far you overshot).

```
// pseudo-code because I'm too lazy to look up ARM SIMD intrinsics, edit welcome
// But I *think* ARM can do these things efficiently, 
// except perhaps the loop condition.  High latency could be ok, but stalling isn't

int count_dups(uint8x16_t v)
{
    int dups = (0xFF == vmax_u8(v));   // count=1 if any elements are 0xFF to start
    auto hmin = vmin_u8(v);

    while (hmin != 0xff) {
        auto min_bcast = vdup(hmin);  // broadcast the minimum
        auto matches = cmpeq(v, min_bcast);
        v |= matches;                 // min and its dups become 0xFF
        hmin = vmin_u8(v);
        dups++;
    }
    return dups;
}
```

**This turns unique values into 0xFF, one set of duplicates at a time.**

The loop-carried dep chain through v / hmin stays in vector registers; it's only the loop branch that needs NEON->integer.

---

#### Minimizing / hiding NEON->integer/ARM penalties

**Unroll by 8 with no branches on `hmin`, leaving results in 8 NEON registers.  Then transfer those 8 values; [back-to-back transfers of multiple NEON registers to ARM only incurs one total stall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951100/debug-data-neon-performance-hazards-in-arm-neon-code#comment86924805_49951100)** (of 14 cycles on whatever Jake tested on.)  Out-of-order execution could also hide some of the penalty for this stall.  Then check those 8 integer registers with a fully-unrolled integer loop.

Tune the unroll factor to be large enough that you usually don't need another round of SIMD operations for most input vectors.  If almost all of your vectors have at most 5 unique values, then unroll by 5 instead of 8.

---

**Instead of transferring multiple `hmin` results to integer, count them in NEON**.  If you can use ARM32 NEON partial-register tricks to put multiple `hmin` values in the same vector for free, it's only a bit more work to shuffle 8 of them into one vector and compare for not-equal to `0xFF`.  Then horizontally add that compare result to get a `-count`.

Or if you have values from different input vectors in different elements of a single vector, you can use vertical operations to add results for multiple input vectors at once without needing horizontal ops.

---

There's almost certainly room to optimize this, but I don't know ARM that well, or ARM performance details.  NEON's hard to use for anything conditional because of the big performance penalty for NEON->integer, totally unlike x86.  [Glibc has a NEON `memchr`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/arm/armv7/multiarch/memchr_neon.S.html) with NEON->integer in the loop, but I don't know if it uses it or if it's faster than scalar.

---

#### Speeding up repeated calls to the scalar ARM version:

Zeroing the 256-byte buffer every time would be expensive, but we don't need to do that.  **Use a sequence number to avoid needing to reset**:

- Before every new set of elements: `++seq`;
- For each element in the set:

  ```
  sum += (histogram[i] == seq);
  histogram[i] = seq;     // no data dependency on the load result, unlike ++
  ```

You might make the histogram an array of `uint16_t` or `uint32_t` to avoid needing to re-zero if a `uint8_t seq` wraps.  But then it takes more cache footprint, so maybe just re-zeroing every 254 sequence numbers makes the most sense.

Comment: BTW, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005281/testing-neon-simd-registers-for-equality-over-all-lanes/49992797#49992797) was part of the inspiration that got me thinking about using `vmin` in weird ways like this.  Related: x86 has [`phminposuw`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PHMINPOSUW.html), so it could do this for 16-bit elements only.  x86 has very few efficient horizontal instructions, others include `psadbw` and `pmaddubsw.  `phaddd` exists but isn't efficient.

Comment: yes, I think if there is a loop condition with neon -> arm then it won't be ok, pure arm (e.g. plain C) would perhaps be even better with some clever algo

Comment: I'm currently rethinking approach that I took in an algorithm that I'm developing (this and other arm neon questions were all related to that). After some sloppy optimization (without trying too hard) results that I got aren't what I was hoping for, I need it to be like 100-1000 faster ;) Basically, some heuristics and shortcuts for most common/expected inputs to skip it all even if results aren't the best.

Comment: I think you have the wrong imagination of SIMD. Neon is basically a very powerful DSP, and your problems are anything else than signal-like

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE is that directed to me? I think I do have reasonable understanding of neon and SIMD in general (having implemented h264 video codecs, arm-nb/arm-wb audio codecs, optimized ffts for echo cancellation like ten years ago. All these things are close to impossible to do if one has wrong imagination of SIMD). I'm not an expert in that stuff and I didn't touch or worked with simd for ages.

Comment: @Pavel: I think Jake is saying that trying to use NEON for problems like this is doomed because of lack of efficient NEON->arm.  *This* isn't a DSP problem, and knowing how to use NEON for DSP isn't helping us solve this problem.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: I updated with more details of my idea for unrolling so you only pay the NEON->ARM stall cost once per group of unrolled iterations.  Did I get this right, that you can transfer multiple registers back to back with only one total stall?  This might not be better than a histogram, though, except maybe if the number of unique values is usually very small.  An ARM that has NEON will also have decent L1d cache, right?

Comment: This absolutely can be done in neon. Imagine I have 16M of 16-byte blocks and for each block I want to calculate number of distinct elements and output 16M ints (or bytes) where each represents number of distinct bytes in corresponding 16-byte block. Would you use arm or try to come up with some clever neon algorithm? So I'm trying, result might be worse than arm/c and as you say it's hard to do it in neon, that's why I'm asking here for ideas. Along the way I might update the algorithm to avoid doing costly stuff in neon.

Comment: I though it was fairly obvious how it can be done, and my question gives hints, but maybe there are clever approaches/tricks?.. So the fairly obvious and hard way to do it in neon: you get min and max, increment 16 lanes by 1, remove max elements from loaded q reg (replace by min), get new max if this one isn't the same as previous max, then increase 16 lanes by 1 again etc. That totally can be done.

Comment: it took me 10 mins to write that `getCountNeon` and perhaps it will be much faster than `getCount` to process 16M 16-byte blocks. It can be improved with some neon and byte tricks. That's basically what the question was about.

Comment: @Pavel: Oh, you have multiple 16-element groups to do in parallel?  Probably do 2 or 3 steps for multiple vectors, then transfers all those results to ARM registers for checking before running any other NEON instructions, using the algo I suggested.  (Again, works best if the number of unique elements is low on average.)  It kinda sucks to deal with some vectors finishing and some not, though.  Maybe in the later passes, skip the iterations for vectors that are done?  Out-of-order exec would be very helpful so you didn't need to interleave work on different vectors so tightly.

Comment: I don't necessarily need to transfer anything to arm, as my basic getCountNeon shows, it can be done purely in neon from 16M 16-byte blocks to 16M bytes array. Things like processing multiple block in parallel are obvious things, I'm just trying to figure out what's the best approach and what opcodes to be used at the core of the algorithm.

Comment: I think this algorithm won't count properly 0xFF values, isn't it? Regarding memchr: I'm not sure how it's implemented in glibc, but I'd expect that it does something similar to what I've done in the past myself (I didn't come up with it, just from reading some ideas): there is a clever trick that you can use to prepare special bitmask from a given byte to make a uin8x16 and then using that bitmask with a few bitwise ops you can see if the byte is present in a 16-byte string (uint8x16). I've done that using plain c++ using 32 or 64-bit ints and it was faster than any assembly (on intel).

Comment: ... as long as that assembly didn't implement the same algorithm obviously.

Comment: @Pavel: `memchr` needs to loop; I wasn't talking about fixed-length 16-byte strings.  Branching on a compare result is not optional.  On Intel for a fixed-length 16-byte string you use `vpbroadcastb xmm1, esi` (AVX512, or separately move + broadcast) then `pcmpeqb xmm1, [rdi]` / `pmovmskb eax, xmm1` / `bsf eax,eax` to find the first set bit with 3 uops / 7=1+3+3 cycles of latency from the vector load being ready to the index of the element in the vector being ready.  (`bsf` sets ZF if the input was all zero, or use other tricks to get a different integer result on not-found).

Comment: @Pavel: Oh, I think you're right; I caught the all-0xFF case but missed the case where some but not all elements are 0xFF.  I guess I need `int dups = (0xFF == vmax_u8(v));`

Comment: @Pavel: I'm not convinced NEON is an obvious win if you always do all 14 iterations of your algorithm, vs. pure scalar.  But maybe re-zeroing the histogram buffer is too expensive?  BTW, updated this with an idea for doing some summing of `hmin` in NEON registers before transferring, or instead of transferring if you can guarantee an upper bound on unique elements.

Comment: Yes, zeroing 256 bytes each time is probably more expensive by itself than my neon version. Also, after that memory was zeroed in neon (memset pretty sure uses neon to clear it) you'll be accessing it in arm which also triggers that same stall afaik

Comment: @Pavel: For repeated use you could zero just the 16 entries that you set to 1, using ARM instructions looping over the source vector again.  Or use a sequence number to avoid needing to reset: `seq++` after every group of 16 bytes, then `sum += (histogram[i] == seq); histogram[i] = seq;`